# Windows Phone 8 keypad dialer from within app

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone

Is it possible to open the windows phone (8) keypad (with the call and save button), from within my app?

I already have the phonecalltask, but this isn't what im looking for, or maybe if it is possible manipulate the phonecalltask someway. I basically want to show a dialer where the user can enter a number and call it, instead of opening the contact list using phonecalltask

thanx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i don't know about the call and save button, but you could have an textbox with `InputScope` set to `TelephoneNumber`.

Then on the `LostFocus` event for that `TextBox` you could call the `PhoneCallTask`

```
 var phoneTask = new PhoneCallTask
            {
                DisplayName = "Name",
                PhoneNumber = txtBoxPhone.Text.ToString()
            };

            phoneTask.Show();
```

so you end up with number input after which u get a prompt asking wether you want to dial the number or not.